# In Perl 5, how to queue a process/application after it reaches a maximum limit

Tags: queue, perl

I have a program that is being symlinked to multiple directories e.g.

> /main/foo.pl
>   /run1/foo.pl -> /main/foo.pl
>   /run2/foo.pl -> /main/foo.pl
>   /run3/foo.pl -> /main/foo.pl
>   /run4/foo.pl -> /main/foo.pl

They're being run as cron jobs, hence I have the following entries in the crontab:

> */2 * * * * /run1/foo.pl
>   */2 * * * * /run2/foo.pl
>   */2 * * * * /run3/foo.pl
>   */2 * * * * /run4/foo.pl

A snippet of **foo.pl** is as below:

```perl
use Fcntl qw(:flock);
use autodie qw(:all);
open my $self, '>', "$FindBin::Bin/lockme";
flock( $self, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB )
    or die "Cannot acquire lock, already running!";

{
    my $long_proc = Process->new();
    $long_proc->run();
}
```

You get the idea, each of the cron process can only run once because there is a lock semaphore check. But run1, run2, run3, and run4 can run simultaneously.

Now what I need is that I want to limit the number of process to maximum of four. If someone adds another cron processes like:

New symlinks:

> /run5/foo.pl -> /main/foo.pl
>   /run6/foo.pl -> /main/foo.pl

Additional crontab:

> */5 * * * * /run5/foo.pl
>   * * * * *   /run6/foo.pl

Both run5 and run6 need to be queued whenever run1, run2, run3, and run4 are all still running. Thus at any given time there will be only 4 processes run.

How can I achieve that? Is there any CPAN module that handles it?

Thanks!

Comment: Am I missing something? The code you show isn't valid Perl. I understand that there is an `or` missing before the `die`, but what is `Process.pm->new()` and why are the last two statements in a bare block? And I can see nothing to say that `run1`...`run4` are special (or is that part the topic of the question?)

Comment: no module required, you can use the semop builtin, if you can figure out how from the somewhat woeful documentation

Comment: @Borodin: thanks, I've fixed the missing or before die().

Comment: @ysth: it seems to be the same idea as pilcrow's answer, looking into POSIX::RT::Semaphore now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see comment from @tsee in @pilcrow answer above. Steffen Muller's *IPC::ConcurrencyLimit* can control the number of concurrenct processes on cooperative multi processing nicely.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few general approaches:

### Quick and Dirty

Have a directory with N lockfiles, and have each process try to lock each file in turn, sleeping a bit.

Caveat:  It's a busy loop, yes, but it might be good enough.

### Daemonic Redesign

Turn `foo.pl` into a local socket-listening daemon, as it is easy for a parent process to manage concurrency of its children.  Turn your cron jobs into blocking requests for the daemon to so something.  (See, e.g., [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parallel-ForkManager/)).

Caveat:  You'll have to carefully re-implement setuid/privilege changing code if you were using cron to run `foo.pl` as multiple different users.

### Interprocess Semaphores, SysV

[IPC::Semaphore](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Semaphore.html) is a somewhat more convenient interface to the SysV `semget` family of functions in [`perlfunc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/semget.html), and the SEM_UNDO flag means that the unexpected process death of one of your workers won't "waste" a semaphore increment.

Caveat:  You'll likely need to create and initialize the SysV semaphore in a separate process, distinct from `foo.pl`, since you cannot create and initialize a SysV semaphore in an atomic operation.

### Interprocess Semaphores, POSIXly

[POSIX::RT::Semaphore](http://search.cpan.org/dist/POSIX-RT-Semaphore/) also supports interprocess semaphores.  The API is simpler than SysV, and semaphores can be exclusively created and initialized to a value in an atomic syscall.

This is probably what I'd use.

Comment: IPC::ConcurrencyLimit does something like your N-lockfiles approach. But it can even span across multiple computers once you outgrow one.

Comment: PS: IPC::ConcurrencyLimit::WithStandby can turn your cron jobs into almost-daemons with a line of code and avoid much of the multiple-busy loops at the same time

Comment: thanks @tsee -- exactly what I need IPC::ConcurrencyLimit saves my day.